# why are my winning conditions not respected (tictactoe)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

total begginner here.

I am trying to write a complete tic-tac-toe program based on the automate boring stuff exercise. I got it working before like this:

```
theBoard = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
            'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}

def printBoard(board): #function to print board
    print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])

print('''
Hi! This is my tic-tac-toe text based game. 
To make your move, write where you want to play:

top-L   top-M   top-R
mid-L   mid-M   mid-R
low-L   low-M   low-R 

''')



turn= 'X' #starting
while True:
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print(f'Turn for {turn}. Where will you play?')
    try:
        move = input()
        if theBoard[move] == ' ':
            theBoard[move] = turn
            if turn == 'X':
                turn = 'O'
            else:
                turn = 'X'
        else:
            print('That move is not possible!')
            continue
    except KeyError:
        print('''Wrong input.
To make your move, write where you want to play:

top-L   top-M   top-R
mid-L   mid-M   mid-R
low-L   low-M   low-R 

''')
        continue
    if ((theBoard['top-L']==theBoard['top-M']==theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['top-L']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['mid-L']==theBoard['mid-M']==theBoard['mid-R']) and theBoard['mid-R']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['low-L']==theBoard['low-M']==theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['low-L']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['top-L']==theBoard['mid-M']==theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-L']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['low-L']==theBoard['mid-M']==theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['low-L']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['top-L']==theBoard['mid-L']==theBoard['low-L']) and theBoard['top-L']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['top-M']==theBoard['mid-M']==theBoard['low-M']) and theBoard['top-M']!=' ')\
        or ((theBoard['top-R']==theBoard['mid-R']==theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-R']!=' '):
        break


if turn == 'X':
    turn = 'O'
else:
    turn = 'X'
print(f'Good Job {turn}, you won!')
```

This worked well and i turned to codereview for some improvements.
I stored the strings 'X' and 'O' as I discovered that those were considered magic strings and make my code less clean.
Next, I wanted to store all the win conditions in a variable called conditions. But when I do this my program will now not get out of the loop when I get a winning move. Why could this be?

```
theBoard = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
            'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
            'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])


conditions = (((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['top-M'] == theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['mid-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['mid-R']) and theBoard['mid-R'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['low-L'] == theBoard['low-M'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['low-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['low-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['low-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['mid-L'] == theBoard['low-L']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-M'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['low-M']) and theBoard['top-M'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-R'] == theBoard['mid-R'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-R'] != ' '))




print('''
Hi! This is my tic-tac-toe text based game. 
To make your move, write where you want to play:

top-L   top-M   top-R
mid-L   mid-M   mid-R
low-L   low-M   low-R 

''')

playerX = 'X'
playerO = 'O'
turn= playerX
while True:
    printBoard(theBoard)
    print(f'Turn for {turn}. Where will you play?')
    try:
        move = input()
        if theBoard[move] == ' ':
            theBoard[move] = turn
            if turn == playerX:
                turn = player0
            else:
                turn = playerX
        else:
            print('That move is not possible!')
            continue
    except KeyError:
        print('''Wrong input.
To make your move, write where you want to play:

top-L   top-M   top-R
mid-L   mid-M   mid-R
low-L   low-M   low-R 

''')
        continue
    if conditions == True:
        printBoard(theBoard)
        break


if turn == playerX:
    turn = player0
else:
    turn = playerX
print(f'Good Job {turn}, you won!')
```

Comment: `conditions` does _not_ dynamically update when the board changes.  It is calculated once, at the beginning of the program, and never changes after that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `conditions` is a `bool` value. It is calculated when it is set. That is to say - it not a function that makes its computations when it is called. In your case `conditions` is set to `False` and it will remain to be `False`. It is a constant.

Wrap it in a function like this:

```
def check():
    conditions = (((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['top-M'] == theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['mid-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['mid-R']) and theBoard['mid-R'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['low-L'] == theBoard['low-M'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['low-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['low-L'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['top-R']) and theBoard['low-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-L'] == theBoard['mid-L'] == theBoard['low-L']) and theBoard['top-L'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-M'] == theBoard['mid-M'] == theBoard['low-M']) and theBoard['top-M'] != ' ') \
or ((theBoard['top-R'] == theBoard['mid-R'] == theBoard['low-R']) and theBoard['top-R'] != ' '))
    return conditions
```

And call this function  instead of `conditions` in the `if` statement:

```
if check() == True:
    printBoard(theBoard)
    break
```

Comment: I meant to say that your `while` loop is infinite because `conditions` is always stays `False`.